# Electrum 4.2.1 GUI - Console payto error

Tags: electrum

I am using Electrum 4.2.1 GUI. I have tried using command `payto` in console and got the error below. What I can do? Is there any new command for this version or I am missing configuration?

```
>>> payto 1JuiT4dM65d8vBt8qUYamnDmAMJ4MjjxRE !
Traceback (most recent call last):
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "electrum\gui\qt\console.py", line 262, in exec_command
  File "<string>", line 1
    payto 1JuiT4dM65d8vBt8qUYamnDmAMJ4MjjxRE !
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```